# Redux action doesn't connect to the saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-saga

In my React application, I use saga middleware. **This is my root saga.**

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import alertSaga from 'redux/alert/alert.saga';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  console.log('ROOT SAGA')
  yield all([
    alertSaga(),
  ]);
}
```

**This is the store.**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from './root-reducer';
import rootSaga from './root-saga';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  INITIAL_STATE,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

**This is my alertSaga.**

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { IAction } from 'constants/types.constant';
import { removeAlert, setAlert } from 'redux/alert/alert.actions';
import { SET_ALERT } from 'redux/alert/alert.types';

export function* displayAlert({ type, payload }: IAction) {
  console.log(type);
  console.log(payload);
  // yield put(setAlert({ type, payload }));

  try {
    yield put({ type: SET_ALERT, payload });
  } catch (error) {

  }

  // setTimeout(() => yield put(removeAlert(payload.id), 3000));
}

function* alertSaga() {
  console.log('HELLO');
  yield takeEvery(SET_ALERT, displayAlert);
}

export default alertSaga;
```

**Finally, this is my alert action.**

```
import { REMOVE_ALERT, SET_ALERT } from './alert.types';

export const setAlert = (payload: Object) => ({ type: SET_ALERT, payload });

export const removeAlert = (payload: number) => ({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload });
```

When the setAlert is dispatched, it doesn't hit to the alert saga. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to export just 1 saga, try below

```
export default function* alertSaga() {
  console.log('HELLO');
  yield takeEvery(SET_ALERT, displayAlert);
}
```

or if you have multiple sagas to export

```
export default function* yourSagas() {
  yield all([
    alertSaga(),
    otherSaga(),
  ]);
}
```